# toUppercase não funciona - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Bom Dia...

Estou usando o toUppercase() no meu projeto, ao realizar testes em um celular Samsung funciona normalmente e fica com caixa alta, mas ao realizar o mesmo teste em celulares Motorola ou xiaome ele não funciona.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser ou o que fazer?

codigo:

```
                AddressInfo addr = new AddressInfo();

                Address address = new Address();
                address.setCEP(cepText.getText().toString());
                address.setXLgr(lgrText.getText().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
                address.setXBairro(barText.getText().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
                address.setXMun(cidText.getText().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
                address.setNro(nroText.getText().toString());
                address.setXCpl(complText.getText().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT));
                address.setFone(phoneText.getText().toString());
                Uf uf = Uf.valueOf(spinnerUf.getSelectedItem().toString());
                address.setUF(uf);
                addr.setAddress(address);

                List<AddressInfo> ll = new ArrayList<AddressInfo>();
                ll.add(addr);
                user.setAddresses(ll);

            }
```

Comment: Poste parte do seu código para entendermos o que está acontecendo, sugiro a leitura de [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel)

Comment: falaram para eu trocar toUpperCase( ) por toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT), mas mesmo assim não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Opa!
Usando getText() você não precisa to toString().

Tente assim :

```
        cidText.getText().toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Suspeito que a diferença de comportamento em dispositivos diferentes se deva ao padrão de estilo de cada um.

Uma forma de se assegurar que o texto será exibido em maiúsculas é na definição do TextView (ou da View que você estiver usando).

Inclusive, creio que fazer dessa forma até melhore o desempenho, já que a conversão para Uppercase ocorrerá apenas na etapa de renderização.

Dito isso, há duas formas de conseguir colocar tudo em maiúsculas:

#### Via XML:

```xml
<TextView
    ...
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    ...
    />
```

#### Programaticamente:

```java
textView.setAllCaps(true);
```

**[Fonte](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:textAllCaps)**